# Can't get filename of document with REST api/CAML query

Tags: 2013, rest, caml-query

Using the rest api to retrieve information about my documents. The documents use managed metadata which isn't expanded correctly when using the stand REST api. So I found [this fix](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/taxonomy-columns-sharepoint-2013-list.html) which uses REST with a CAML query. That has been working very well up to now. The CAML query I use is

```
        var caml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                      "<Query><Where><And>" +
                          "<BeginsWith>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='FileRef' />"+
                            "<Value Type='URL'>"+filterStr+"</Value>" +
                          "</Begins>" +
                          "<Neq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />" +
                            "<Value Type='Number'>"+this.APPROVAL_STATUS.rejected.val+"</Value>" +
                          "</Neq>" +
                      "</And></Where>" +
                          "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='FLSequence' Ascending='TRUE' />" +
                          "</OrderBy>" +
                      "</Query>" +
                    "</View>"
```

This retrieves all kinds of information about my document, ID, Title, custom columns, properly expanded metadata columns. But the one thing it doesn't return **is the name of the file**!

In my searching the main problem people seem to be working on is how to filter by file name in a CAML query which doesn't help me much. I did try adding **ViewFields** in there:

```
<ViewFields>
     <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
     <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
     <FieldRef Name='Name' />
   </ViewFields>
```

But none of those pulled back the file name AND it also stopped returning all the other good info.

In this situation how would I go about retrieving the name of a document? Is there some kind of wildcard select all fields for a CAML query? Am I just SOL?

Comment: I also found https://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/sharepoint-internal-field-names-sharepoint-2010/ and tried BaseName and NameOrTitle, neither or which returned the name of the document.

Comment: It seems I can use the FieldValuesAsText, FieldValuesAsHtml, or FieldValuesForEdit __deferred uri to make another REST call and request the file name. This seems to be a bit over the edge complicated for getting the file name.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `?$expand=file` to the end or your Url.  And don't specify the ViewFields in the query.

For Example

```
var url = ($"{SPConfiguration.BaseAbsoluteUrl}_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{listTitle}')/getitems?$expand=file");
```

Comment: Are you saying that I can add REST $expand and $select query strings along with the CAML query for the filtering? This was quite a long time ago, but I don't think it ever occurred to me to combine the two.

Comment: @Rothrock you can combine the two,  there are few query string parameters that don't work, but the $expand does.   (IRC the paging can't be in query string when posting CAML)

Answer (score 0):

This one is an alternative that I prefer to CAMLing with REST, but requires you to have the item ID and list ID.

```
var query = webUrl + '_api/web/lists(guid'<your list ID>')/items(<item ID>)/File;
```

Then you get the document name directly into `data.d.Name`.

I am unsure why CAML wouldn't bring FileLeafRef.

Comment: I'm using CAML with REST. I can't just use REST because we are using managed metadata which isn't properly expanded in REST. I could try rewriting the whole thing as a straight up CSOM/CAML query but most of the other things on the site/page are already using REST. I'm also trying get information on about 20 to 30 things at a time, so I'd prefer not to have to get all the IDs and then make second requests for all the info.